# Port below x86 program to mips32

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, mips

Below sample code for X86 arch,

```
#  define INC(_lval,_lqual) \
      __asm__ __volatile__ ( \
      "lock ; incl (%0)" : /*out*/ : /*in*/"r"(&(_lval)) : "memory", "cc" )
```

Please somebody help me equivalent MIPS32 arch.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like gcc inline assembly for an atomic increment.  This is the gcc intrinsic for an atomic increment:

`__sync_fetch_and_add(&_lval, 1);`

Works on x86, mips32, etc.

Comment: getting undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4 for mips32

Comment: @ding_dong: you should also have seen a warning then, at least this is what the gcc documentation states.

Comment: If gcc didn't implement it on that architecture, as your error message and Jens's answer suggests, then I'm afraid I won't be of much help.  The MIPS32 Architecture manual shows that MIPS32 has load-linked conditional store, you'll need to use that to build atomic increment.

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that might be useful for you [here](http://gasnet.cs.berkeley.edu/dist/gasnet_atomic_bits.h). It seems in fact to indicate that the builtin for gcc is not implemented for that architecture.